# How can I optimize Nuxt.js performance when running with PM2 compared to without PM2?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, deployment, nuxt.js, pm2

I'm currently working on a Nuxt project and I'm running it using PM2 with 16 instances. I've conducted a benchmark comparing the performance with and without PM2 (single-threaded), but surprisingly, I haven't observed any significant differences in the benchmark results.

Here's the content of my `ecosystem.config.js` file:

```js
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: 'NuxtAppName',
      exec_mode: 'cluster',
      instances: process.env.INSTANCES,
      script: './node_modules/nuxt/bin/nuxt.js',
      args: `start -c ${process.cwd()}/nuxt.config.js`,
    },
  ],
}
```

For speed testing, I'm using the following command:
`ab -n 1000 -c 20 http://localhost:3000/x/1/`

Here are the benchmark results with PM2:
[image: Benchmarck with pm2]

In this test with PM2, the Requests per second (throughput) is 15.13/sec.

Now, let's take a look at the test results without PM2:
[image: without pm2]

In this test, the Requests per second (throughput) is 10.14/sec.

My question is, why is the difference in performance so minimal, almost on par with the single-threaded test? What steps can I take to improve this performance gap?

Comment: Interesting. How many cores? Is there a chance there are app-specific bottlenecks like DB or disk?

Comment: @EstusFlask 8 cores with ssd disk, backend have a 120/sec throughput and i dont think so have bottleneck there

Comment: Probably because your benchmark is not stressful enough or just doesn't test the right thing in node.